# Entity Framework not generating complex type?

Tags: entity-framework

I have created a function Mapping for a stored procedure.  The stored procedure returns data from a straightforward table variable

```
  DECLARE @tblResults TABLE(
  KeyName VARCHAR(100), 
  ID INT IDENTITY, 
  DataType INT, 
  DayNo INT, 
  Consumption FLOAT, 
  SeriesName VARCHAR(20), 
  DayType INT, 
  DayKey VARCHAR(20))
```

I have setup the complex type as normal and it is not available as a complex type?

I have gone into the Designer.cs file and added [Key()] to the KeyName field but this still does not work.

Comment: The top user for Entity Framework questions lives in Europe.  If you don't get an answer right away, check back in about 8 hours http://stackoverflow.com/tags/entity-framework/topusers

Comment: more to the point response times on SO are best effort not SLA and largely depend on how well written the question is and its complexity

Comment: ok thanks, hope this is enough information.  I really dont have a clue whats wrong or how to fix it and I am really running out of time.  For some reason EF is not generating an Entity Class for this function import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this thanks.  I had forgotten that I needed to create a new ObjectQueryable method in the web side of my solution to return objects of the new type.  Without that, the type would not have been transferred to the silverlight application side.  As soon as I added that, removed all generated code and regenerated it worked :)  I did still have to manually add the Key attribute to my key fields as this stung me before but I was ready for that one!  I really need to find a way of stopping EF from caching things, but thats covered in my other question